# Play! 2.0 + Spring + MyBatis example in Java

Tags: java, spring, playframework, playframework-2.0, mybatis

I have been trying to find an example app using

Play! 2.0 + Spring + MyBatis in Java but without success.
(I am already aware of Scala example but I don't have much experience in it)

I have experience working with Spring + MyBatis and would like to make the most leverage out of what I already know and at the same time be able to work with Play!.

Does anyone know where I can find such an example?

Comment: Are you looking for integrating play2 with mybatis or spring with mybatis? It seems u r already familiar with spring+mybatis. Play is a web framework and interacting with mybatis directly from Play may not be a good design. I think all u need is how to integrate Play with Spring. Am i correct?

Comment: The main reason why I am interested in integrating the 3 frameworks is not to use ebean(I find it much comfortable and efficient working with sql). Also, I would like to save time bootstrapping everything together and so was looking for an existing example.

Comment: I don't have much idea on Play..but i think you can hookup Play Controller with Spring Container and you know how to use Spring+MyBatis.

Comment: I am sorry but your comment doesn't really help. Thanx though.

Comment: Here is something close: https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars/tree/java-spring  It's Play 2.1 + Spring + JPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [howto that shows integration of mybatis with play 2.1 managed controllers](http://inoio.de/blog/2013/02/07/integrating-mybatis-guice-play2/) using [mybatis guice](http://www.mybatis.org/guice/). Using [mybatis-spring](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/) with spring managed controllers should be a direct replacement.